# Regarding Menu Bar in netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

In Netbeans 8.2 version how to shift position of menu bar from top to middle of the panel in Netbeans 8.2 ?
I have tried this in properties but couldn't find the error.

Comment: What error are you talking about?

Comment: I want to add my menubar at the middle of the page instead of top of the page. Is it possible in net beans ?